# Is this usage of the nginx if-directive safe?

Tags: ssl, nginx

According to their own documentation, [`if` is Evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/). They gave several examples that certain configurations will not work if an `if` directive is used. They don't go into detail as to why it behaves <s>wrong</s> differently than the user may expect, or give examples on how to rewrite those instances.

What they do however is to link to [this article](https://agentzh.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-nginx-location-if-works.html), which gives a rudimentary explanation that an `if`-directive within a `location`-directive creates another "pseudo-`location`", which ignores the other `location` blocks.

However, the examples seem counter-intuitive to me, even with the explanation. As such, I wanted to know if my specific configuration is safe, and if not, how it could better be re-written. I did my own testing of course and it seems to behave correctly. The following example is only the relevant fragement of the configuration file:

```
ssl_client_verify optional;

location /public {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location / {
    if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS)
    {
        return 403;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

My main security concern is that I want to avoid exposing any content that is not in `/public` to anyone who does not have a valid certificate.